# Devextreme overlay controls show up as two instances

Tags: overlay, popover, multiple-instances, devextreme, dx-data-grid

I am using Devextreme dxDataGrid control in my page and I am facing the issue that Delete confirmation dialog and Drag-Drop overlay shows two instances instead of one.

Following are the screenshots:
[image: Delete confirmation dialog has 2 instances]

[image: Row dragging preview shows 2 rows]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is resolved after removing dx-viewport css class from my View page.

Comment: thank you for this. Wasted an hour debugging.